# Avoid empty headers with fancyhdr in two-side article class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, article

I'm using this configuration for headers:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\arabic{page}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}% Current section
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}% Current subsection
```

In the below example all works right until page 5. Then I have an empty space in the left header. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}     
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}     
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}     
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{Hahahaha}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Two}
\subsection{Hihihihi}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Blala}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{QWERTY (bis)}
\subsection{ASDF}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load the package lipsum and replace all your blabla with  \lipsum[1-2]. This will make it much easier to copy and paste your code.

Comment: Also replace `\input{preambulo}` with the necessary code to make the document compilable and demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What @UlrikeFischer says plus what's in preambulo?  If I replace your preambulo with \usepackage{fancyhdr}, I see no problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. I have already done. The preambulo was a mistake. With the new code, see left header of page 5.

Comment: `\rightmark` prints the first right mark of the page and this is set to empty by the \section command. Also it is not clear which header should be shown there. `3.1 ASDF` would look odd in combination with `2 Two`  from page 4, and `2.2 Blala` would be wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What would be the solution? Chnage the package? Redefine the marks?

Comment: The main problem is not technical but logical. Such header works fine with chapter and section because chapter always start a new right page which normally has a plain page style. What header do you want to get there? What header when the \section is not directly at the start of the page but some lines down?

Comment: If that happens, I would like the new section or subsection in the header